# conversion from to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c++

im new to c++ programming, however I have done some programming in java, so I am not completely new to OO programming.

What I am trying to do is create structure, and then an array of objects of that structure. I am trying to keep that array always sorted (using newbie sorting), so what I do is define the structure and then create an array[50] of that structure, and helping variable of that structure. Then every new entry of different variables (name, last name, grades, etc..) I get from the user I put into helper variable. Then, when user finishes typing all the data in helper variable, i go on and figure out at what position in the array should that object be put.

Here is sample code, ill try to keep it as simple as possible.

```
struct student {
    //declaring variables that student should have
};

student students[50];
int numOfStud=0;

while (a=='y' && numofStud<50) { //a=='y' just means user wants to add more students
    student input= new student;
            //adding various data to student     
            //adding input into an array of students using variation of insertion sort algorithm
cout << "want to add more students?";
cin >> a;
}
```

When i try to compile this i am getting errors at `student input= new student`. So I am a bit confused now.

Off topic: Also I have a question about what happens when you do for example `students[0]=input;` am i creating another copy of object here, or am I just creating another pointer (like in java), and therefore both students[0] and input will point at the same object?

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A successful call to `new T` returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated `T` object, so you are trying to instantiate a `student` from a pointer to `student` here:

```
student input= new student;
```

You just need

```
student input;
```

When you do

```
students[0]=input;
```

you are assigning the value of `input` into the `student` instance that is located in `students[0]`. So `students[0]` and `input` will be different objects.

Comment: Awesome, that cleared it for me. Thanks again. :D Also thanks to all the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` keyword is for allocating memory on the *heap* using pointers. You only need

```
 student input;
 // fill "input" with data
```